# DataGridCell background coloring

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

In my WPF application, I need to paint the background of a specific `DataGridTextColumn` cell with some color. Here is what I tried:

```
DataGridCell cell = ...
cell.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
```

Upon execution, I do see a little bit of yellow color near the right edge but the color does not cover the complete cell.

I figured it must be the TextBlock content that is getting painted on top of my yellow color. Therefore, I added the following code:

```
TextBlock content = cell.Content as TextBlock;
content.Text = "abc";
content.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
```

This results in a background color behind the text "abc." The rest of the cell is still colored in white.

I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you provide a little more code on how the xaml is laid out?

Comment: You should be doing this in XAML using a `Trigger` or a `DataTrigger`. See the [Binding WPF Datagrid cell background colour with trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841649/binding-wpf-datagrid-cell-background-colour-with-trigger) question here on StackOverflow for an example.

Comment: Sheridian. Why would you remove WPF from the title? When I look at your questions, you have WPF in almost all of your titles.

Comment: I don't have any xaml code. The column is built dynamically. Plus, ForeGround attribute works fine from the code. It is just the background that is giving the problem.

Comment: @Peter: I think you can use styles. Specify an explicit style for `DataGridCell` in App.xaml, or with the key and in the code for each cell set the Style. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @Peter, this website uses Tags. Your question already has the WPF Tag, so it will already be returned in searches for anybody that watches that tag. Furthermore, the `DataGridCell` word in your title *also* specifies that this question is a .NET question... it's quite clear what your question is about. As for your comment *you have WPF in almost all of your titles*, that's just ridiculous. Either way, sometimes a Tag is required if it adds something to a title, but not the way that you used it... as a Tag. If it *really* bothers you... just put it back.

Comment: You can examine your visual tree more closely using a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/87261).