# Is it possible to move the style for DataGridCell to another, separate file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I put the styles directly in a bound DataGridTextColumn, I have access to the bound propertie's value ("Position" in this case). If I move the styles to a separate file, I no longer have access to that propertie's value but still need the trigger. How can I acomplish it? I have tried to get the bound value of the DataGridCell in a converter but it is always null, like if the converter run before the data binding.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Position}" Header="Position">
       <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
             <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Position,  Converter={StaticResource ValueToBooleanConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
       </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: "If I move the styles to a separate file, I no longer have access to that propertie's value but still need the trigger" - actually you _do_ - your code will still work. XAML Bindings are evaluated at runtime, not compile-time.

Comment: @Dai Ok, thanks for clarification :) Even then, the property is not always called "Position". Is there any way to get the value of the DataGridCell's bound property in the style if it's in a separate file?

Comment: Does this help? It's not the exact same problem, but it does concern binding a column's binding to a the same column's bound data-source property https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841649/binding-wpf-datagrid-cell-background-colour-with-trigger

Comment: @Dai I really appreciate the effort but it's still for setting styles in the same file as the controls (and not in a separate file)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of, which enables you to split xaml code into another file is by using a `ResourceDictionary`.

So you create a new Resource Dictionary in Visual Studio and then add your Style and dependent Resources. I.e.:

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">

     <local:ValueToBooleanConverter x:Key="ValueToBooleanConverter" />

     <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Position, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBooleanConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

That way you can then reference the new Style from your original file (Important: you will have to access it by a Key, or by Type).
Afterwards your original xaml code should look similar to this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="resdict.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Path=Position}"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}"
            Header="Position" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Note, that you have to reference the Dictionary by it's file name.

Comment: Ok, my problem is how to make the bound property name ("Position" here in the resource dictionary file) not static but dependant on what property the styled cell/column is actually bound to?

Comment: You mean, as in if you rename the property in the .cs file, the property in the xaml file gets renamed too? Otherwise I don't quite understand what you mean by dependent.
In case i'm right, afaik there is no way to propagate your "renaming" of a property from a .cs file into a xaml file.

Comment: In the "<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Position ", I will know the name of that property "Position" only I apply the style to some cell and (would like to) get the property name that the column of that cell is bound to and have it in place of "Position" (which just assumes the Property is named "Position".

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The DataTriger is supposed to listen to a specific Property , so that it can check the Value of the Property. 
Let's say instead of "Position" you have a "Phone Number" Property. Since Position and Number will most likely not share the same Datatype, it's not possible to run the same check for both Properties and expect the same Result.
Long Story short: you will most likely be forced to define a unique Style for each DataGridTextColumn you want to support.